# OLS linearity assumptions

Tags: regression, least-squares, stata, diagnostic, linearity

Do we have to check on stata that the OLS assumptions of linearity of a regression if the regression is already linear in parameters? I'm having trouble with this concept.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Linearity is used in two different ways here.  The functional form of the conditional mean may or may not be linear.  This is the assumption you have to validate.  This is usually done by plotting residuals against predictions.  The resulting cloud of dots should be centred around the y=0 line.

Comment: @DemetriPananos, I would plot residuals against regressors instead. Hm, better not instead but in addition.

Comment: @RichardHardy  Yea, good point.

Comment: I would suggest adding LOESS or other scatterplot smoothers to those plots as well. It is hard to see nonlinearity in the presence of a dense and highly variable scatter.